# ValidationMonitor triggered only once

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to use Tensorflow's `ValidationMonitor` on `DNNRegressor.fit`

but it gets triggered only once when `global_step = 1`. How to fix it?

The `every_n_step` setup to 1 like this

```
validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(
    test_dataset.data,
    test_dataset.target,
    every_n_steps=1)

regressor = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[2],
                                            model_dir="/home/maciej/tf-logs")


regressor.fit(x=train_dataset.data,
               y=train_dataset.target,
               steps=1000, 
               monitors=[validation_monitor])
```

What I get on stdout are logs about loss and a single one about validation:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 201: global_step = 201, loss = 5.50003
INFO:tensorflow:Validation (step 201): loss = 5.50003, global_step = 201
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 96.1045
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 6.3935, step = 301
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 154.978
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 4.77587, step = 401
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 158.06
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3.72956, step = 501
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 151.51
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3.04578, step = 601
```

This is also confirmed on tensorboard.

The full code and logs are available here:
https://gist.github.com/maciejjaskowski/9f791e517f379c41d20cc72619909fe6

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [Monitoring tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/monitors),
 ValidationMonitors rely on saved checkpoints.

Consider adding checkpoints every x seconds with:

```
config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=5)
```

This worked for me.